# How to see the Matlab code behind a Matlab function

Tags: matlab, github, statistics, probability

There is a function in Matlab called [`copulafit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulafit.html). How can I see the code that underlies this function? Many numpy and scipy functions for Python are readily open source on Github, but I can't find Matlab functions on Github for some reason

Comment: Matlab is not open source, so you won't  find its code on GitHub. On the other hand, Octave is free and open source, and is mostly compatible with Matlab. You may want to take a look. However, it seems that [Octave does not include `copulafit`  (yet)](https://wiki.octave.org/Statistics_package#Missing_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MATLAB installed you can either highlight the function name then secondary/right-click and select `Open "copulafit"` or alternatively type `open copulafit` in the command window. Yeah, I believe MATLAB isn't open source as of this posting time/date. Possibly why the reason for the lack of GitHub resources. Octave might be something that might be interesting to look into.

[image: Function Evaluation]